# I want to pick other columns based on col 'Name1"

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like a result set of Name1, Data1 and Data2 if the name in col Name1 matches the name in col Name2.

Is that done in macros or in which area?

```
Name1     Name2     Data1      Data2
Al Bain   Win Vung Al@test.com 800-777-7777
Sue Reed  Al Bain
```

Answer (score 0):

*Conditional VLOOKUP array (CSE) formula solves the issue:*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Formula in cell `L53`:

  ```
  =IF($L47=$M47,VLOOKUP($L47,$L$47:$O$49,{1,3,4},FALSE),"No Match")
  ```
- Drag the formula Right (`L53:N53`), then press `F2` and finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.

**N.B.** *Now the formula will be wrapped with `{ }` brackets and looks like,,*

```
   {=IF($L47=$M47,VLOOKUP($L47,$L$47:$O$49,{1,3,4},FALSE),"No Match")}
```

- Fill formula down.

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*